# Getting compilation error "JavaScript heap out of memory" while adding multiple web workers in the angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, heap-memory, web-worker

I am getting the following compilation error in Visual Studio Code while adding multiple web workers in the app.

I have added web workers in the app as the following structure.

```
async executeWorker1() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (typeof Worker !== 'undefined') {
        const worker = new Worker(new URL('../workers/app.some1.worker', import.meta.url));
        
        worker.onmessage = ({ data }) => {
           receiving values...
          }
          worker.terminate();
          resolve(true);
        };
        worker.postMessage(passing values...);
      } else {
        reject(false);
      }
    });
  }

async executeWorker2() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (typeof Worker !== 'undefined') {
        const worker = new Worker(new URL('../workers/app.some2.worker', import.meta.url));
        
        worker.onmessage = ({ data }) => {
           receiving values...
          }
          worker.terminate();
          resolve(true);
        };
        worker.postMessage(passing values...);
      } else {
        reject(false);
      }
    });
  }

async executeWorker3() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (typeof Worker !== 'undefined') {
        const worker = new Worker(new URL('../workers/app.some3.worker', import.meta.url));
        
        worker.onmessage = ({ data }) => {
           receiving values...
          }
          worker.terminate();
          resolve(true);
        };
        worker.postMessage(passing values...);
      } else {
        reject(false);
      }
    });
  }

async executeWorker4() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (typeof Worker !== 'undefined') {
        const worker = new Worker(new URL('../workers/app.some4.worker', import.meta.url));
        
        worker.onmessage = ({ data }) => {
           receiving values...
          }
          worker.terminate();
          resolve(true);
        };
        worker.postMessage(passing values...);
      } else {
        reject(false);
      }
    });
  }
```

But after adding web workers in such manner, I am getting the compilation error in Visual Studio Code.

```
⠧ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)...
<--- Last few GCs --->

[4952:00000204555A4F50]   103198 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 2030.4 (2079.1) -> 2030.4 (2078.6) MB, 694.2 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.162, current mu = 0.000) allocation failure GC in old space requested
[4952:00000204555A4F50]   103895 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 2030.4 (2078.6) -> 2030.4 (2077.9) MB, 697.3 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.088, current mu = 0.000) last resort GC in old space requested


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF659FC79CF v8::internal::CodeObjectRegistry::~CodeObjectRegistry+114207
 2: 00007FF659F56096 DSA_meth_get_flags+65542
 3: 00007FF659F56F4D node::OnFatalError+301
 4: 00007FF65A88B1EE v8::Isolate::ReportExternalAllocationLimitReached+94
 5: 00007FF65A8757CD v8::SharedArrayBuffer::Externalize+781
 6: 00007FF65A718B9C v8::internal::Heap::EphemeronKeyWriteBarrierFromCode+1468
 7: 00007FF65A725849 v8::internal::Heap::PublishPendingAllocations+1129
 8: 00007FF65A72281A v8::internal::Heap::PageFlagsAreConsistent+2842
 9: 00007FF65A715479 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage+2137
10: 00007FF65A714542 v8::internal::Heap::CollectAllAvailableGarbage+130
11: 00007FF65A7136BF v8::internal::Heap::AllocateExternalBackingStore+2143
12: 00007FF65A731340 v8::internal::FreeListManyCached::Reset+1408
13: 00007FF65A7319F5 v8::internal::Factory::AllocateRaw+37
14: 00007FF65A74399E v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::AllocateRawArray+46
15: 00007FF65A7465DA v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::NewFixedArrayWithFiller+74
16: 00007FF65A746833 v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::NewFixedArrayWithMap+35
17: 00007FF65A54CBE3 v8::internal::HashTable<v8::internal::EphemeronHashTable,v8::internal::ObjectHashTableShape>::EnsureCapacity<v8::internal::Isolate>+243
18: 00007FF65A56475C v8::internal::ObjectHashTableBase<v8::internal::EphemeronHashTable,v8::internal::ObjectHashTableShape>::Put+556
19: 00007FF65A5695FD v8::internal::JSWeakCollection::Set+173
20: 00007FF65A475602 v8::internal::CompilationCache::IsEnabledScriptAndEval+7586
21: 00007FF65A918EE1 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+494417
22: 00007FF65A913B9C v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+473100
23: 00007FF65A9128EB v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+468315
24: 00000204583649CF
```

I have tried to increase the NODE_OPTIONS in Environment Variables by --max-old-space-size=10240 (10 GB) and also executed the below command in a PowerShell terminal before running my project.

`set NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=10240`

Also I have updated Node to v18.16.1, but nothing works for me.